# Use ReactJS and Axios to give data to API in PHP

Tags: php, reactjs, rest, axios

I'm working on creating a basic ReactJS Frontend App that has to send data to an API created with php. My react app is hosted on localhost:3000 using XAMPP and the php file is hosted on localhost:8000. when I try to connect to it I get a connection refused error. I use Axios to send a Post request.
I know this might be very general but any ideas to how to solve this. or go about programming that App?

This is what it currently is. I get a net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED whenever I call it
`axios.post('http://localhost:8000/file.php', someData)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure there's a config option in Axios to specify port, you should be able to send a post request to that port like this:

```
axois.post('http://localhost:8000')
    .then((success) => {
        console.log(success)
    })
```

Comment: Tried that but it still gives me a net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Sounds like it's a problem with Cross Origin requests. I'm not really a back-end guy but try adding header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); to the PHP file that's handling that request.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a proxy in your package.json file:

`"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"`

Read more: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#proxy